# Sending command confirmation to windows console

Tags: java, windows, console, zlib

I have successfully called a Windows console from java to decompress a string using zlib like this:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start z -d psw.txt", null, new File("C:\\users\\dlopez\\Encrypted\\ "));
```

After this I'm asked if I want to overwrite the file and Ihave to indicate yes but I don't know how to do it also from java, after executing the command.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: are you really using the rather old zlib binary ? My suggestion: either get a current unzip program or use a Java library to do the extraction. Have you checked if there is a parameter that tells zlib to silently overwrite ? If not you could write the "y" to the outputstream of the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve it using the -r command

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start z -d -r psw.txt", null, new File("C:\\users\\dlopez\\Encrypted\\ "));
```

This way I replace the file without asking if I want to

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to a console prompt like this:

```
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start z -d psw.txt", null, new File("C:\\users\\dlopez\\Encrypted\\ "));
    new PrintWriter(proc.getOutputStream()).println("y");
```

Comment: Thk for your replies.
I have tried new PrintWriter but that doesn't work. Can it be beacuse the console is from zLib itself?

Comment: Right, this way you can only communicate over stdin and stdout that OS provides to each process, not through application's UI. In the particular case of ZLIB, you can use it directly from Java as mentioned here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html